# How to add image along with title name for all pages in that project in one code in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, favicon, tiles

I wrote the mentioned code

```html
<link rel="Shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico"/>
```

in head section of JSP page and it is able to display the image along with the title name of the page
but what I want is it should be reflected on all my pages of project.  So what should be done ?

Note: Made a `favicn.ico` and environment is Java Struts 2

Comment: <link rel="Shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico"/> this is the code written in one of my page and it works.

Comment: Don't put your code in the comments, edit it into your question.

Comment: it is not displaying that link so how can  i display it ?

Comment: Format it as code by highlighting it and click CTRL+K

Comment: yeah done ! did you mark my question as negative ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a main page called for example `baseLayout.jsp`, which has a section for header, body, footer, toolbar, etc.

Each section you should include using Struts `include` tag or similar. In this page you have a `head` where you can put your `link` tag. As well as this page will be returned by every action, with exception to those actions that return redirect like results, you will have a link on every page.

This is the same concept that used in Tiles framework, where you can define a layout in the tiles config file and use `tiles` result type to return by the actions.

Another approach is to create a JSP file with only the link and include it on every page, but it's less productive as above solution.

If you are not familiar with Tiles framework you can read
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15554374/573032) answer to get started.

> > I'm thinking of using simple features such as a side bar for navigation and banner across the top with the website name etc, and would like this to be carries across every page.
>
> you are definitely needed tiles and tiles integration with Struts 2 via the [tiles-2 plugin](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/tiles/) or [tiles-3 plugin](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/tiles-3/)
>
> there's plenty tutorials with examples on the web on these theme, for example
>
> - [Struts 2 Tiles Integration Tutorial](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-tiles-example-1.html)
> - [Struts 2 Tutorial Series – How to insert Tiles to your project](http://www.programcreek.com/2010/03/struts-2-tutorial-series-how-to-insert-tiles-to-your-project/)
> - [Struts 2 Tiles Plugin Tutorial with Example in Eclipse](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/struts-2-tiles-plugin-tutorial-with-example-in-eclipse/)
> - [Struts 2 Tiles Framework Integration Tutorial Example](http://www.javatpoint.com/struts-2-tiles-framework-integration-tutorial-example)
> - [Struts2 Tiles Example](http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts/struts2.2.1/struts2-tiles-example.html)
> - [Working With Struts 2 Tiles, Struts 2 Tiles Example](http://www.java4s.com/struts-tutorials/working-with-struts-2-tiles-struts-2-tiles-example/)
>
> > I have read that to do this in JSP I have to use tag files (stored in the WEB-INF folder) then link to these on each JSP page?
>
> Tags is a bit outdated, however in the JSP you should use [struts tags](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/tag-reference.html)
>
> > Also I have seen people creating these banners and sidebars etc in Photoshop, is this what normally goes on in web site development?
>
> Yes, that banners, images, designed with it.
>
> > To sum it up: Creating a decent looking web page whilst using JSPs and the Struts 2 framework.