# Receiver class org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesInitializer does not define or inherit an implementation of resolved method createContainerFactory

Tags: struts2, struts, tiles, apache-tiles, struts2-tiles-plugin

Could someone point me to a possible solution? We're migrating a really old Struts2.3/Spring4/Hibernate4 application to **Struts 2.5.30 / Hibernate 5.2.1 / Spring 5.2.21**. Also, the legacy app had **Tiles** **2.2.2** which we haven't changed. We're keeping Tiles 2.2.2 as is.

```
<properties>
    <log4j.version>2.17.2</log4j.version>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <finalName>oar</finalName>
    <spring.version>5.2.21.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>
    <struts.version>2.5.30</struts.version>
    <tiles.version>2.2.2</tiles.version>
</properties>
```

With these Maven dependencies, when the app launches, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesInitializer
   does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract
   org.apache.tiles.factory.AbstractTilesContainerFactory 
   createContainerFactory(org.apache.tiles.TilesApplicationContext)' 
   of abstract class org.apache.tiles.startup.AbstractTilesInitializer.
```

Full stack trace:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesInitializer does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract org.apache.tiles.factory.AbstractTilesContainerFactory createContainerFactory(org.apache.tiles.TilesApplicationContext)' of abstract class org.apache.tiles.startup.AbstractTilesInitializer.
    at org.apache.tiles.startup.AbstractTilesInitializer.createContainer(AbstractTilesInitializer.java:123)
    at org.apache.tiles.startup.AbstractTilesInitializer.initialize(AbstractTilesInitializer.java:70)
    at org.apache.tiles.web.startup.AbstractTilesListener.contextInitialized(AbstractTilesListener.java:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4753)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5215)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
```

Per the Version Properties above, the relevant Struts & Tiles dependencies are below. Note that **struts2-tiles-plugin is included**, with the version  as per the property, 2.5.30. (My understanding is that there's also a newer *struts2-tiles3-plugin* but I'm not using that, since our Tiles is kept at 2.2.2.) Could the problem actually be that we're keeping Tiles 2.2.2 which is incompatible with Struts 2.5.30? We don't want to switch to Tiles 3, because there are a lot of differences (e.g., `useAttribute` has changed).

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
        <version>${struts.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-json-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${struts.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${struts.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-tiles-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${struts.version}</version>
    </dependency>
            
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${struts.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-jquery-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
            
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.bootstrap</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-bootstrap-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
        <version>${tiles.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>${tiles.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-el</artifactId>
        <version>${tiles.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>${tiles.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>${tiles.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-ognl</artifactId>
        <version>${tiles.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${tiles.version}</version>
    </dependency>
            
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-template</artifactId>
        <version>${tiles.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: You can’t arbitrarily mix-and-match library versions; the Tiles plugin has a [dependency on Tiles 3.0.8](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts2-tiles-plugin/2.5.30). Things can change between versions.

Comment: Which Tiles plugin? We are using struts2-tiles (not tiles3), and Tiles 2.2.2.

Comment: The one in the link.

Answer (score 0):

The Struts 2 framework used a plugin for integration with Tiles framework. The plugin for Tiles 2 is struts2-tiles-plugin and for Tiles 3 is struts2-tiles3-plugin. You should not define the version of Tiles in your `pom.xml` because it is incurred from the transitive dependencies for each plugin. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32358332/573032) answer which has links to examples with the  Tiles integration. Note how the version is defined

```xml
<struts2.version>6.0.0-RC3</struts2.version>
```

and

```xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-tiles-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

If you specify Tiles version separately in your configuration, it can be incompatible with one from the plugin dependencies and you have probably exlude it to resolve the error.